# Cursor over matplotlib canvas in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a GUI package on Python with Tkinter module and using matplotlib via *FigureCanvasTkAgg* to show some graphical data. I also want to interact with this visual representation of the data via *canvas.mpl_connect* method. Everything works just fine, but I do not satisfied with default arrow-like cursor: it does not allow precise clicking on my data (the actual "click point" does not match with the tip of the arrow) and also it hides from user some area near the click pint. So the question is how to change the default cursor? I tried change it through Tk config methods (like *master.config(cursor="tcross")*), but apparently matplotlib canvas has its own cursor configuration because this string only changes appearance of the cursor above all parts of main window except MPL canvas, above canvas the default arrow is still being shown.

Comment: There's not a complete system to do so, but have a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/cursor.html  (Note that blit will work just fine on TkAgg, as well. If you're using blitting elsewhere in your code, you'll need to worry about synchronizing things, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: Thank you! It is very interesting solution, but is there any possibility to hide/disable the mean cursor (arrow)? Now I can see both the arrow cursor and this nice MPL Cursor widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a couple of caveats: I'm about to dive into some implementation details.  I think the toolbar was recently refactored, so some of this could change with the next version of matplotlib.  Furthermore, this values I've specified for the cursor only apply to the `TkAgg` backend. The general concept is similar for other backends, but the location of `cursord` and the backend-specific cursors will vary.  As an example for `Qt4Agg`, the `cursord` dict is in `backend_qt4` instead of `backend_qt4agg`, and the values are Qt cursors: e.g. `QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor`.

As I mentioned in my comment, have a look at [matplotlib's `Cursor` widget](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/cursor.html).  However, the broader issue of how to customize the cursor(s) matplotlib uses is a bit hairier.

The reason that you can't directly change the cursor matplotlib uses (e.g. `master.config(cursor='whatever')`) is that the default toolbar overrides it (different cursors for different tools on the toolbar).

One option is to not add the toolbar. In that case, you can just call `parent.config(cursor='tcross')` and be done with it.  However, you presumably want the toolbar to be present for easier panning/zooming/etc.

The toolbar uses a dict of present cursors for each tool: `backend_tkagg.cursord`.  The keys for this are `int` codes, so it's a bit more readable to refer to them through `matplotlib.backend_bases.cursors`.  The default tool is the `cursors.POINTER`.

As a quick example (For simplicity, I'm using the `pyplot` interface to build the canvas, figure, etc.)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backend_bases import cursors
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg

# Change the default cursor to any valid TK cursor
# To hide it, you'd use the string "none" (or possibly "no" on windows)
tkagg.cursord[cursors.POINTER] = 'coffee_mug' 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()
```

Note that you can also control the cursor for any tool (e.g. zoom, pan, etc) in the same way.  Your options are `cursor.HAND`, `cursor.POINTER`, `cursor.SELECT_REGION`, and `cursor.MOVE`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! This solution is exactly what I wanted and works well. One small bug: when cursor is moved out from MPL area, it does not change back to default shape (i.e. in the beginning the cursor is arrow, then, when I move it to MPL area, it turns to cofee_mug or whatever, but when I move if out, it still in mug shape).
I figured out, that this bug can be fixed, if the shape of the cursor is explicitly selected via `config(cursor='arrow')` method for other widgets.

Comment: Is there an updated solution to this issue?

tkagg.cursord leads to an attribute error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002098/attributeerror-tkagg-has-no-attribute-cursord

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking at this question now (like me), matplotlib has since been updated and 'cursord' moved locations in matplotlib version 2.1.2. This is why the previous answer is probably giving you errors now.

To change this you have to replace the line
`import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg`
to
`import matplotlib.backends._backend_tk as tkagg` instead.