# Set hand cursor for picking matplotlib text

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have embedded a matplotlib figure in tkinter's `Toplevel` and added text in the figure using `axes.text`. I set `picker` property of the text to be `True` as I want do something when user clicks the text. Now I want to change the mouse cursor of `arrow` to `hand` when mouse moves onto the text. I know for any widget of tkinter, this can be achieved by setting `cursor='hand2'`. However, it seems that this is the problem for matplotlib. So, how can I achieve this? My OS is Windows. Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, this looks to be a duplicate, but if that's a mistake, let me know and I'll re-open the question.

Comment: @Joe Kington this is not duplicate to that question. What I want to do is change mouse's cursor when it is over the text, not add cursor in the figure, as matplotlib's Cursor does.

Comment: If you don't think it's a duplicate, I'll leave it open, but either way, you'll need to change the cursor for the active tool in `tkagg.cursord`, identical to the answer I originally linked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603215/cursor-over-matplotlib-canvas-in-tkinter)  The only difference is that you'll only want to do it when hovering over a particular text object.  You have to jump though a couple of hoops for the last bit, but not too many.  (I'll add a complete example later if I have time.)

Comment: @JoeKington I have learned your answer in your linked question carefully, but I do not get the point about `tkagg.cursord`. And no detailed introduction about the `Cursor` class is published on the Internet. So can you provide more about your point? Thanks again.

Comment: The matplotlib `Cursor` widget doesn't have anything to do with this question.  (It draws interactive "crosshairs" on the axes.)  To change the cursor that's visible when using the TkAgg backend, you need to change `tkagg.cursord`, which is why I was mentioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to change the backend's `cursord` lookup.  (E.g. for TkAgg, it's `matplotlib.backend_tkagg.cursord`.)  Otherwise, the navigation toolbar will override whatever you manually specify through Tk.

There's an additional wrinkle if you need things to occur "on hover".  Because matplotlib doesn't have a hover event, you'll need to connect a callback to all mouse motion and then detect whether you're over the artist in question.

This example is for the TkAgg backed, but it's essentially identical for other backends. The only differences are in the imports and in the way that cursors are specified (e.g. on Qt, you'd want a Qt cursor object instead of something like the string `"hand1"`).

```
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg

def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'TEST', ha='center', va='center', size=25)
    fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('motion_notify_event', OnHover(text))
    plt.show()

class OnHover(object):
    def __init__(self, artist, cursor='hand1'):
        self.artist = artist
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.default_cursor = tkagg.cursord[1]
        self.fig = artist.axes.figure

    def __call__(self, event):
        inside, _ = self.artist.contains(event)
        if inside:
            tkagg.cursord[1] = self.cursor
        else:
            tkagg.cursord[1] = self.default_cursor
        self.fig.canvas.toolbar.set_cursor(1)

main()
```

Comment: Excellent, it works. Thanks very much. But in my situation in which `matplotlib.figure.Figure` is used to embed `matplotlib` into `tkinter`, `figure.canvas.mpl_connect` should be applied instead of `fig.canvas.callbacks.connect`, otherwise an `AttributeError` will be raised. This raises another question that, `fig` obtained from `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()` are all `<matplotlib.figure.Figure object>`, why `None` is returned by `fig.canvas` in latter `fig` and therefore error is raised when using `canvas.callbacks.connect`?

Comment: One more question, can I get a label or value that indicates zoom or pan button in toolbar is activated or inactivated? Current bug is that the connection is suppressed when toolbar button is clicked, but mouse cursor remains to be hand over text. One solution I can get is defining label using `text.set_label()` and checking the label in `OnHover` to identify whether zoom or pan is activated. If so, set `inside` to `False`. But this seems to be verbose. Any suggestion?

Comment: Second question is solved by disconneting the `'motion_notify_event'` using `figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)` when zoom or pan button is activated.