# AttributeError: tkagg has no attribute cursord

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

I recently reinstalled anaconda to shift the directory over from an admin account to my personal account.

Previously, I had no issue with the code below

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
defaultcursor = tkagg.cursord[1]
```

Now, it gives the following error:
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg' has no attribute 'cursord'

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I found out that tkagg has no cursord after matplotlib ver 2.1.2. What is the new way of handling cursors in the newer matplotlib vers?

Comment: `cursord` is a dictionary. One may question the usefulness of indexing it. Especially since you would achieve the same via `defaultcursor = "arrow"`.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, sorry. The attribute 'cursord' still exists, it just moved locations, but you're still able to handle cursors in newer matplotlib versions over tkinter.

Your code should work now if you change your import line from `import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg` to `import matplotlib.backends._backend_tk as tkagg` instead. Hope this helps!